# How to change metatags dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, meta

I am working on a site where the meta tags are set in a Masterpage in a  section using runat="server". I can update the title, description, keywords, etc... through properties in the Masterpage code-behind, but how would I add or edit non-basic ones such as

I have tried the following, but it always returns 0 for the count.

```
   Dim header As Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead
            header = TryCast(Me.Master.FindControl("headerIdName"), Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead)
            Dim count As Integer = header.Controls.Count
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I retrieve a custom meta tag in a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362452/how-do-i-retrieve-a-custom-meta-tag-in-a-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate through the controls in the header:

[How do I retrieve a custom meta tag in a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362452/how-do-i-retrieve-a-custom-meta-tag-in-a-page)